# Show $\max_{r\equiv (r_1,..., r_M) \in \mathbb{R}^M} \sum_{k=1}^M \mu_k r_k - \log\Big(\sum_{k=1}^M \exp(r_k) \Big)= \sum_{k=1}^M \mu_k \log(\mu_k)$

Tags: functions, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, maxima-minima

I am struggling with the following maximisation problem. Take a vector $\mu\equiv (\mu_1,..., \mu_M)\in \mathbb{R}^M$ such that $\mu_k\in [0,1]$ $\forall k=1,...,M$ and $\sum_{k=1}^M \mu_k=1$.

I want to show that

$$\max_{r\equiv (r_1,..., r_M) \in \mathbb{R}^M} \sum_{k=1}^M \mu_k r_k - \log\Big(\sum_{k=1}^M \exp(r_k) \Big)= \sum_{k=1}^M \mu_k \log(\mu_k)$$

I write first order conditions 
$$
\begin{cases}
\mu_1-\frac{\exp(r_1)}{\sum_{k=1}^M \exp(r_k)}=0\\
...\\
\mu_M-\frac{\exp(r_M)}{\sum_{k=1}^M \exp(r_k)}=0\\
\end{cases}
$$
$$
\Updownarrow
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
r_1=\log(\mu_1)+\log(\sum_{k=1}^M \exp(r_k))\\
...\\
r_M=\log(\mu_M)+\log(\sum_{k=1}^M \exp(r_k))
\end{cases}
$$
and **assuming that this is the maximum**, we can put it in the objective function and get the result.

Now I need to ensure that we have a maximum and at this point I'm lost in the 
computation of the Hessian because I get many zeros. Could you help me with that part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are done if you prove that the function is concave, that is the function log-sum-exp is convex. Two ways to do it is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2418554/why-log-of-sum-of-exponentials-fx-log-left-sum-limits-i-1n-e-x-i-righ?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/650218/convexity-of-matrix-soft-max-log-trace-of-matrix-exponential). Another way is to use induction: prove first that $\ln(1+\exp{t})$ is convex and increasing. Then

1. $\ln(\exp{r_1}+\exp{r_2})=r_1+\ln(1+\exp(r_2-r_1))$ is convex.
2. Assume $\ln(\sum_{i=1}^M\exp{r_i})$ convex. Then
   $$
   \ln\Big(\sum_{i=1}^{M+1}\exp{r_i}\Big)=r_{M+1}+\ln\Big(1+\sum_{i=1}^M\exp(r_i-r_{M+1})\Big)=r_{M+1}+\ln\Big(1+\exp\underbrace{\ln\sum_{i=1}^Me^{r_i-r_{M+1}}}_{\text{convex}}\Big)
   $$
   is convex.

P.S. You can also prove it [via Hessian](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/henry/teaching/w10/367.w10/367miscfiles/pages48to60.pdf).

Comment: Thanks. Can you remind me why if $\log(\sum_{y=1}^M \exp(r_k))$ is convex, then the objective function is concave?

Comment: @CGT From the general properties: linear is concave, negative convex is concave, sum of two concave is concave. For concave functions, a critical point is the global maximum.